# Linux command line change Windows Executable Assembly Info

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, version, executable

Is there any chance to change, from Linux command line(server) assembly info for a windows executable? Like changing the version, or any other Information.

I want to create a dynamic executable based on queries user specified on my website, and I don't want to add a unique id in file name(not name_123.exe, but name.exe with the "123" in Assembly Info).

Is there any chance to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a hex editor, right?

On Linux you can install hexedit that would help you doing that.